# Sum of consecutive rows if they meet a condition

Tags: r

I am using R to analyze a time series containing monthly values of a Drought Index (SPEI). The data has the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(
  spei = c(-0.52677,-0.33412, -0.89412 ,0.83459,0.65078,-0.59507,-1.16728,-1.42036,-1.47762,-1.73324,-1.23006,-1.10954), 
  month = c(7:12, 1:6), 
  year = c(rep(1992, 6), rep(1993, 6))
)
```

I would like to obtain the duration of the drought events based on this definition: number of consecutive months with the index (`spei`) lower than a certain threshold (-0.86 in this case).

Any help?

Comment: What is the expected output for this example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach the problem. We use the results from [**`rle`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) to find out how long the current streak is (using `lengths` from `rle`), and then we create a `drought` variable using `values` and `lengths` from `rle`:

```
r_l <- rle(df$spei <= -.86) #runs of drought variable

(drought_df <- data.frame(streak = unlist(sapply(r_l$lengths, FUN = function(x) 1:x)),
           drought = rep(r_l$values, r_l$lengths),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

   streak drought
1       1   FALSE
2       2   FALSE
3       1    TRUE
4       1   FALSE
5       2   FALSE
6       3   FALSE
7       1    TRUE
8       2    TRUE
9       3    TRUE
10      4    TRUE
11      5    TRUE
12      6    TRUE
```

And then you could `cbind` back to the original table:

```
cbind(df, drought_df)

       spei month year streak drought
1  -0.52677     7 1992      1   FALSE
2  -0.33412     8 1992      2   FALSE
3  -0.89412     9 1992      1    TRUE
4   0.83459    10 1992      1   FALSE
5   0.65078    11 1992      2   FALSE
6  -0.59507    12 1992      3   FALSE
7  -1.16728     1 1993      1    TRUE
8  -1.42036     2 1993      2    TRUE
9  -1.47762     3 1993      3    TRUE
10 -1.73324     4 1993      4    TRUE
11 -1.23006     5 1993      5    TRUE
12 -1.10954     6 1993      6    TRUE
```

#### edit

If you just want the longest streak of droughts, you can use:

```
max(subset(drought_df, drought)$streak) # subset drought_df for only drought periods
[1] 6
```

Comment: I upvoted, but I think he really just wants `max(rle(df$spei <= -.86)$lengths)`

Comment: I added an edit that allows for this calculation. thanks

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper But wouldn't that only give the maximum drought run when he wants all of the drought runs? Quick-n-dirty modification to your code: `rle(df$spei <= -.86)$lengths[rle(df$spei <= -.86)$value]`

Comment: @Lyngbakr that's dirtier than necessary. my edit is a (IMO) cleaner way

Comment: OP will clarify if necessary ;)

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know the results expected but this also might give an insight:

```
 transform(df,drought=ave(x<-spei<=-0.86, cumsum(!x), FUN = cumsum))
       spei month year drought
1  -0.52677     7 1992       0
2  -0.33412     8 1992       0
3  -0.89412     9 1992       1
4   0.83459    10 1992       0
5   0.65078    11 1992       0
6  -0.59507    12 1992       0
7  -1.16728     1 1993       1
8  -1.42036     2 1993       2
9  -1.47762     3 1993       3
10 -1.73324     4 1993       4
11 -1.23006     5 1993       5
12 -1.10954     6 1993       6
```